# How does an ElementHandle differ from a DOM Element?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

The documentation on [page.$(selector)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector) says it returns a promise containing an ElementHandle.

But the documentation on [ElementHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) is a bit lacking.

It says it "represents a DOM element", but what does that really mean? And if does represent the DOM, why can't the contents of the ElementHandle be inspected?

It also says, "prevents DOM element from garbage collection unless the handle is disposed." Why would a DOM element get garbage collected if the browser is still on the page?

---

This came up because I thought it'd be simple to grab the text from an element on the page, so I tried,

```
const text = await page.$('#text').textContent;
```

which returned `undefined`. So I tried,

```
const text = await page.$('#text').textContent();
```

which threw an error.

Turns out the correct way is

```
const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#text').textContent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, I thought it was just me!

Answer (score 10):

With ElementHandle can you still access to properties like `textContent` but in "Puppeteer way". 
Firstly you must [`.getProperty()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname) on [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle), and after that convert it to [`.jsonValue()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#jshandlejsonvalue). Remember that all this operations returns poromises so you should `await` on all of them like this:

```
await (await (await page.$('#text')).getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
```

Here is full working example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="text">Sample content</div>
  </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#text').textContent);
  const text2 = await (await (await page.$('#text')).getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();

  console.log(text);
  console.log(text2);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Hi. looking at `const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#text').textContent);` - who said that `'#text'` will be 
 already available at this point ?  I know it's not ajax injected , but still - shouldn't we "`waitFor*`" ?   - in other words , does the `goto` waits for `load`  event and _then_ resolve the await ?

Comment: Yes, we should `waitFor` it. I didn't include this part for sake of simplicity in this example.

Comment: Re-reading the docs , I think we can skip the waitFor : https://i.imgur.com/hKRnkCI.jpg . it's default to `load` event which is the last one

Comment: You didn't answer the question: WHAT IS an ElementHandle